# Apache ECharts Sankey not responsive to different screen sizes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sankey-diagram, apache-echarts

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
   <div ref={chartRef} style={{ width: '100%', height: '600px' }} />
</Grid>
```

Set the chart width to `100%` but when changing the browser to different screen size, the chart size remains as the width in previous screen.

Example: Laptop screen extend with monitor screen

- In laptop screen, chart display perfectly. The chart size remains when move the chart to monitor screen.
- To make the chart size width fit the monitor screen, I will need to refresh the page.
- Same goes when move the chart back to laptop screen. The chart width is overflow and refresh needed.

I expected the chart width is responsive to the screen size.

Comment: https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.resize